# K-mean clustering, Number of samples smaller than number of clusters

Tags: python-2.7, k-means

I'm very new to K-means, so I hope somebody can help me with the following issue.

```
mbk = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=3, init_size=400, batch_size=300, verbose=1).fit(model_dm.docvecs[20000])
```

but I get this error:

```
 /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)

ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-43cf0431aa1e> in <module>()
      6 
      7 
----> 8 mbk = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=3, init_size=400, batch_size=300, verbose=1).fit(model_dm.docvecs[20000])
      9 
     10 

/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
   1236         n_samples, n_features = X.shape
   1237         if n_samples < self.n_clusters:
-> 1238             raise ValueError("Number of samples smaller than number "
   1239                              "of clusters.")
   1240 

ValueError: Number of samples smaller than number of clusters.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `model_dm.docvecs[:20000]` because if that is a list you were calling only it's 20001st element:

```
mbk = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=3, init_size=400, batch_size=300, verbose=1).fit(model_dm.docvecs[:20000])
```